# True and False in python can be reassigned to False and True respectively?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I think I just witnessed something really scary and hard to digest!

So in my projects I came across this beautiful piece of code

`from CoreDefaults import FALSE, TRUE`

After looking into the `CoreDefaults` module I saw this

```
TRUE = 1 == 1     # some part of my mind was blown here
FALSE = 0 == 1    # which I honestly thought was clever and it really is!
```

But then it raised a question that when python gives default True and False why would anyone evaluate the value of True and False and then assign to such variables but then I got a hunch that the only reason anyone would do was if those values can be reassigned!

So I tried the following

```
>>> True
True
>>> False
False
>>> True = False   # True is assigned to False and it is NOT OK ?
>>> True
False              # Python, I think it's over between you and me.
```

Is this behavior normal ? Is this the way it's supposed to be implemented ? Why not make it non-editable ? Is this a security risk when using python or is it the same with other languages too ? Any clever way of making it more non-editable like any builtin I need to override ? How do I fall asleep tonight ?

I'm using python 2.6.6.

EDIT 1 :
So can we use 0 and 1 instead of False and True instead ? I think it's more fail proof though ?

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work in python 3.6 : "cant assign to keyword"

Comment: Making something non-editable is creating a special case. Python tries to avoid special cases. And Python lets you shoot your own foot if you really insist on it.

Comment: Yes, in Python2 `True` and `False` are simple variables, that can be assigned with new values. Nothing to worry about, because each module has its own global scope.

Comment: If you're using a version of Python which was released in _August 2010_, worrying about rebinding of builtins is the least of your problems.

Comment: @Daniel : So in one module True could be True and in some other module scope True could be False ? bc that would be even more insane  !

Comment: @d-coder: `True` and `False` are simple names, and therefore belong to some scope, as any other variable. Why don't you worry about any other constant being overwritten?

Comment: @Daniel : I did not try with other variables but I ( or any other python fanatic) would expect True to be true as the keyword/constant/variable says it is!

Comment: @d-coder: and `True` will be true, until you change it, consciously. And everybody sees it at once, when she/he looks for `True = something`.

Comment: @Daniel : Hmm. So should we be using 0 and 1 instead of True and False ? It really sounds fail proof though.

Comment: @d-coder: it's always fail proof, because you control your code and so nobody overwrites `True`.

Comment: @Rohi the behaviour is 2.x specific. The change was made [in 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Python 2, `True` and `False` are builtin "constants". You are quite right about it not being safe. But Python doesn't actually have constants, so to make it impossible to assign a different value, they need to be keywords. `True` and `False` are keywords in Python 3. But it would have been disruptive to add these new keywords to Python 2.

Comment: "You are quite right about it not being safe." From a security standpoint? Perhaps I'm suffering from a failure of imagination, but can you elaborate on this? Keeping in mind that any attack strategy beginning with "first, the attacker gains write permissions on your source code" will be effective whether True and False are writable or not.

Comment: Who said anything about an attacker? It isn't safe because it makes it possible to accidentally change the value of something that you know (or in this case, believe you know) is a constant. Consider a list of boolean values that you pass into a function, and then mistakenly assign a value to an element of that list (because you got the order of the parameters wrong). And so on.

Comment: I suspect "you are quite right about it not being safe" was meant from the perspective of code reliability, although OP did ask about security. Whether or not people should be able to shoot themselves in the foot is definitely subjective, and Python leans towards giving programmers power to do whatever.

Comment: "who said anything about an attacker?" - Oh, I thought you were replying to OP's question, "Is this a security risk[?]". If you're just talking about how a user could fat-finger an assignment and get a bunch of truly weird bugs, I agree that's possible.

Answer (score 3):

BoarGules answer is mostly correct but incomplete.  The built-in bool type and built-in `False` and `True` were add in one of the 2.2.z releases.  (This was before the 'no new features in maintenance releases' rule.  Indeed, the confusion engendered by the mid-version addition is one of the reasons for the rule.)

Before this addition, people who wanted to use `False` and `True` had to write something like the following near the top of their code.

```
False, True = 0, 1
```

Making `False` and `True` uneditable keywords would have broken existing code.  That would indeed have been distruptive.  After the addition, people could optionally edit their code to

```
try:
    False
except NameError:
    False, True = 0, 1
```

in order, when running with newer 2.x releases, to have `False` and `True` be bools, and print as 'False' and 'True' instead ints printing as 0 and 1.

In 3.0, when most people had dropped support for 2.2 and before, and hence no longer needed the assignment alternative, `False` and `True` were made keywords.